# incompatible pointer types assigned to CCActionInterval from CCAction

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am currently going through the excellent 'Learn cocos2D by rod strougo and ray wenderlich', but I seem to have hit a snag. I'm on chapter 2 at the moment and I keep getting the error 'incompatible pointer type assigning yo CCActionInterval *'from 'CCAction *'.
I downloaded the source code as a test and ran it, and I still seem to get the same error.

Comment: sorry, that would require me to upload a whole project which stackoverflow is incapable of doing. It's the project in chapter 2 of the book.

Comment: What, every line of your code gives you "incompatible types" warning?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue introduced by a newer version of Xcode. The compiler checks more thoroughly, and in this case it correctly reports an error.

You can bypass the error by fixing the pseudocode lines from:

```
CCActionInterval* action = [self getSomeAction];
```

and casting the returned action to CCActionInterval*:

```
CCActionInterval* action = (CCActionInterval*)[self getSomeAction];
```

So add `(CCActionInterval*)` in front of whatever action is returned and assigned to the left-hand variable. This is called casting.